# Convert MS Access Crosstab query to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, pivot

I'm trying to convert MS Access Cross Tab query into SQL Server stored procedure but having issue with pivoting data in SQL Server.

Here's the MS Access cross query I want to convert -

```
TRANSFORM Sum(NZ(Actuals!Amount,0)) AS Amount
SELECT Actuals.PS_OV, Actuals.Period, Actuals.Program, Actuals.Actuals_Year
FROM Actuals
GROUP BY Actuals.PS_OV, Actuals.Period, Actuals.Program, Actuals.Actuals_Year
PIVOT Actuals.Source;
```

Values from the `Source` column (i.e. `Equipment, Expense, Furniture, Leasehold`) are pivoted to columns. Kindly advise how to do this in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server your [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would like be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT PS_OV
    , Period
    , Program
    , Actuals_Year
    , IsNull(Amount, 0) as Amount
    , Source
  FROM Actuals
) x
PIVOT
(
  Sum(Amount)
  FOR Source IN ([Equipment], [Expense], [Furniture], [Leasehold])
) p
```